# Overflow-anchor dont work with scroll top position

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have column with scroll. For stop content jump i use overflow-anchor: auto.

**Use cases:** (you can try on sandbox. left column. after 3 second on scroll touch added items before):
https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/oWgENp

```
<div class="on">
  <p>long content</p>
</div>
.on {
  overflow-anchor: auto;
}
```

1) scroll to center , items added to start, no jump - **ok**

2) scroll to end, items added to start, no jump - **ok**

3) touch scroll and seek to start, items added to start, jump exists - **fail**

How i can stop jump on use case 3?

Comment: Same problem here. The anchor seems to work if there's even a bit scrolled down, but not if it's at the absolute top.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin i think it other problem. Any solution exists ?